# For a web application which employs application layer encryption, is there anyway to modify post parameters which is captured encrypted in burp.?

Tags: encryption, web-application, penetration-test, appsec

- There is client side javascript controls in place which restricts malicious characters.
- All form data is transmitted via POST requests. In burp, I can see that all parameters are encrypted into one parameter and sent over the network.
- INISafe SFilter need to be installed at the client side (something which filters inputs, encrypts traffic, antikeylogger)

I need to test for XSS and other forms of vulnerabilities and so need to modify the parameters. Does anyone have any interesting ideas to work around this.?

Comment: Are you sure the data is encrypted instead of simply encoded? Front-end encryption is the most pointless thing so I doubt many people do it.

Comment: You can remove all the Javascript controls that are in place before you load the page in the browser. Further, from your description, the encryption/encoding is also being done client side and after the fact which means that it is not concerned with what you have entered, it is just encrypting/encoding it. I don't see why you can't test for XSS or any other input vulnerability.

Comment: @billc.cn Yeah, the data is encrypted. Not many people do it. First time I am also encountering this. :D

Comment: @void_in Actually its not just javascript. There are client side applications like INISafe SFilter. So, we really can't even type in anything into the forms, as it is filtered by this client side application. Any suggestions, anyone.?

Comment: What kind of encryption?

Comment: @korockinout13 I haven't figured that out yet. But I am only looking for a way to modify the parameters after it is entered in the form fields and before it is encrypted and sent.